# Hi, I'm trying to do automation testing using robotframework and appium library for mobile application how can i check if the app is already installed

Tags: appium, adb, robotframework, appium-android

Like I mentioned I need to check if the application that I'm trying to automate is already installed in the device. If the app is not installed I need to install the application.

In order to check the app is already installed in the system I tried the Appium Library keywords such as Execute adb shell, Activate Application and Run Process from the Process library.
for the Execute adb shell keyword I gave the parameter as adb shell pm list packages -e emulator-5554 ${appPackage}

for the Activate Application keywork gave the parameter as the ${appPackage}.

These didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thankyou.

Need to get the status of the app whether the application is already installed in the android emulator that I'm currently using for automating.